# collect items in shopping basket and then pass basket to paypal. possible?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I know there is a Paypal button and an easy way to implement Paypal in your website. But if you want to do it a little bit more elegant you need to adapt too much. So I have a question if this scenario is possible:

The user is on my website and puts some items into a small basket (programmed with javascript). Now he has for example 3 items in his basket and he clicks "pay". Now I want to forward the user and the content of his basket to Papyal where he can make the checkout.

Is there a way to forward the user to Paypal and transmit the data of the basket to Paypal (price, name of the item ect.)?

I would be also happy if someone can give me a hint where I could find more about this.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already looked at the "add to cart" paypal feature? https://www.paypal.com/al/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_shoppingcart-intro-outside

Comment: yes it is possible, you can send item_0, item_1 and price_0,price_1,price_2 etc as perameters..try checking out documentation.. https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside

Comment: thanks for these links. I will try it!